# Weird issue where vectors of size 3 returns some odd values

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

I am learning C++, so I decided to play around a bit and create a program that makes a linked list of the size and values that the user inputs. Then it outputs the values in a linked list.

For example, when I enter a size of `3` and enter my three values as `3,4,7` or whatever three numbers I want. It should output `3,4,7`.

However, the output I receive is `3, 0, 0`. It outputs the first value then `0, 0`.

It works properly for sizes greater than 3 and less than 3. Just not for 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node * next = nullptr;
    Node(){}
};
Node * head = nullptr;

int main() {
    //takes input of what size you want to create the linked list
    int d_size = 5;
    cout << "Enter the desired size: " << endl;
    cin >> d_size;
    vector<int> num;
    int s = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < d_size; i++){
        int input;
        cout << "Enter desired value "<< (s) << endl;
        cin >> input;
        num.push_back(input);
    }

    Node* head = new Node();
  
    Node * temp = head;
    temp->data = num[0];
    for (auto itr = num.begin(); itr != num.end();++itr){
        temp->next = new Node();
        temp->next->data = num[*itr];
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp = head;
    //creates the linked list
    cout << "Printing Linked list: " << endl;
    //prints out the linked list data
    while(temp->next != nullptr){
        cout << temp->data<<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << "Linked List printed!"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `temp->next->data = num[*itr];` in your second  loop gives undefined behaviour if any of the elements of `num` is greater than or equal to the number of elements.    That happens with the second and third element you enter.  `itr` is an iterator, not somethig you dereference to obtain an index (which seems to be what you're TRYING to do).

Comment: An iterator isn't an index, so `num[*itr];` doesn't make sense in this context. You want `temp->next->data = *itr;` instead.  It looks like you'll add the first item to your list twice too.

Comment: bruh i had a massive brain fart. Im on 4 hrs sleep. thx

Comment: @MohammedAli Linked Lists are not a newbie topic, as it involves multiple advanced topics (memory management, pointers, etc) which newbies tend to struggle with (we get TONS of questions on StackOverflow related to botched linked list implementations). Since you seem to already have knowledge of classes and standard containers, you should use the standard [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container instead, and let it handle the details for you. Get comfortable with using that first, then learn the lower level details later on after your skills have grown.

Answer (score 0):

iterating over a vector is different from arrays, an iterator (which is what auto is making itr) is a pointer to the value in the vector. In your loop itr is a pointer to the value in the vector so *itr is the value in the vector. You need to change the line `temp->next->data = num[*itr];` to `temp->next->data = *itr;`.